# How to override parent theme actions

Tags: actions

Working on a child theme. 
On the parent theme functions.php there is a 'widgets_init' action where four sidebars are regsitered. I need to remove three of those sidebars.

What is the propper way to do this?

I already tried :

1) creating a 'widgets_init' functions on the child theme (different function name) with higher priority, with only one 'register_sidebar'. Not working, the four sidebars are still there.

2) remove parent action with remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'wp_bootstrap_starter_widgets_init' ); Not working, the four sidebars are still there.

Then, I tried adding a custom function on the child theme for the 'widgets_init' action, and then, I do a "unregister_sidebar" for each of the sidebars I want to remove. This works, but I don't kmnow if is the best way.

I want to do it the RIGHT way.

Comment: You can't `remove_action` for a hook that hasn't been added yet. Note that a child theme `functions.php` loads *before* the parent theme.

Comment: You have the right solution. It’s unregistering the sidebars.